# timeout issues in spring integration gateway for soap request and reply

Tags: spring-integration

I am facing some chellenge while setting the timeout for the soap request to ESB interface from my interface(Using spring integration). While sending the request to ESB interface, I am setting the request timeout = 5000ms and reply timeout = 5000ms but in case the services is down on ESB interface, the request is not timeout in the desired timeout time of 5000ms(5 sec) and timeout sometimes in 40sec or more. I tried to use the default request timeout and default reply timeout options also with the int:gateway configuration but the same issue. Please see the below configuration done:

```
<int:gateway id="SoapESBGateway"
            service-interface="test.soap.service.ServiceSoap">
            <int:method name="ServiceResponse"
                request-channel="RequestChannel" reply-channel="ReplyChannel"
                request-timeout="5000" reply-timeout="5000" />
        </int:gateway>

        <int:chain input-channel="RequestChannel" output-channel="ReplyChannel">
        <int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller" result-transformer="resultTransformer"></int-xml:marshalling-transformer>

        <int:transformer ref="TransformerBean" method="transformMethod"></int:transformer>

        <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="ws-SoapESB-gateway" ignore-empty-responses="true" uri="${soap.URI}"></int-ws:outbound-gateway>

        <int:transformer ref="TransformerBean" method="transformMethod"></int:transformer>

        <int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer unmarshaller="marshaller"></int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer>
        </int:chain>


        <bean id="resultTransformer" class="org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.ResultToStringTransformer" />
        <bean id="TransformerBean" class="test.TransformerImpl"></bean>
```

Please let me know if I am missing something while setting the timeout option.

Thanks,
Vinay A

---

updated:

```
<int:gateway id="SoapESBGateway"
                service-interface="test.soap.service.ServiceSoap">
                <int:method name="ServiceResponse"
                    request-channel="RequestChannel" reply-timeout="5000" />
            </int:gateway>

            <int:chain input-channel="RequestChannel">
            <int-xml:marshalling-transformer marshaller="marshaller" result-transformer="resultTransformer"></int-xml:marshalling-transformer>

            <int:transformer ref="TransformerBean" method="transformMethod"></int:transformer>

            <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="ws-SoapESB-gateway" ignore-empty-responses="true" uri="${soap.URI}" message-sender="messageSender"></int-ws:outbound-gateway>

            <int:transformer ref="TransformerBean" method="transformMethod"></int:transformer>

            <int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer unmarshaller="marshaller"></int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer>
            </int:chain>


            <bean id="resultTransformer" class="org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.ResultToStringTransformer" />
            <bean id="TransformerBean" class="test.TransformerImpl"></bean>

<bean id ="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="2000"></property>
    </bean>
```

As above, I have added messageSender bean reference with the int-ws:outbound-gateway and set the property connectiontimeout = 2sec but I can still see that this is waiting around for 19sec for first hit when network is down and for the next hits, less then 19 sec but not the desired timeout for the first hit at least. So do we not have any option where we may ascertain that the desired timeout work always.

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please, read this chapter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#d4e4197

According to your config you have `direct` flow, so there is no reason to have `request-timeout` and `reply-channel`.

The issue of your `40sec` is under that WS gateway's `WebServiceMessageSender`. In your case it is `HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender` by default. And there is some `connectTimeout` attribute in the `HttpURLConnection`.

I'm not sure how we can change it, but I prefer to use `HttpComponentsMessageSender` to have more control over HTTP connections.

Now the question `Why is it 40sec, but not those 5sec from reply-timeout?`. Because your thread is blocked on the `send` and it hasn't reached to the `wait reply` part yet.

Comment: Hi Artem, I am still facing the timeout issues when incorporated changes as suggested. I have updated the my query area with the issues I am still facing. Need your suggestion please.

Comment: I'd suggest you to debug to determine which part of your program takes that time. BTW, there is another option on that `Sender` - `readTimeout`.